# AWS Active MQ STOMP Issue

Tags: spring, stomp

I am having issues with the Amazon MQ implementation of topics. When I use the in memory `SimpleMessageBroker` clients receive only messages that they have subscribed to. However with the externalized message broker, all clients receive all messages broadcast through the `SimpMessagingTemplate`.

relevant code:

```
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
        if ("true".equalsIgnoreCase(environment.getProperty("aws.activemq.enabled")))
            config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
                    .enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic")
                    .setUserDestinationBroadcast("/user")
                    .setRelayHost(this.activeMQCreds.getHost())
                    .setRelayPort(this.activeMQCreds.getPort())
                    .setClientLogin(this.activeMQCreds.getUsername())
                    .setClientPasscode(this.activeMQCreds.getPassword())
                    .setAutoStartup(true)
                    .setSystemLogin(this.activeMQCreds.getUsername())
                    .setSystemPasscode(this.activeMQCreds.getPassword())
                    .setTcpClient(this.createClient());
        else config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
                .enableSimpleBroker("/topic");

    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
        registration.interceptors(webSocketSessionChannelInterceptor);
    }

    private TcpOperations<byte[]> createClient() {
        return new ReactorNettyTcpClient<>(
                (client) -> client.remoteAddress(this::getAddress).secure(), new StompReactorNettyCodec());
    }

    private SocketAddress getAddress() {
        try {
            InetAddress address =
                    InetAddress.getByName(this.activeMQCreds.getHost().replace("stomp+ssl://", ""));
            return new InetSocketAddress(address, this.activeMQCreds.getPort());
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            log.error("Exception", e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

How we are handling subscriptions:

```
public class WebSocketSessionChannelInterceptor implements ChannelInterceptor {

    @Override
    public Message<?> preSend(final Message<?> message, final MessageChannel channel) throws AuthenticationException {
        log.info("Message: {}", message);
        final StompHeaderAccessor accessor = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);

        try {
            final String destination = accessor.getDestination();
            if (StompCommand.CONNECT == accessor.getCommand()) {
                final String token = accessor.getFirstNativeHeader("Authorization");
                final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken user =
                        webSocketAuthenticatorService.getAuthenticatedOrFail(token);
                if (user != null) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(user);
                accessor.setUser(user);
            } else if (StompCommand.SUBSCRIBE == accessor.getCommand()
                    && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(destination)
                    && destination.contains("conversations?orgId=")) {
                String orgId = destination.substring(destination.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);
                if (WebSocketAuthenticatorService.hasPermissionToOrgId(orgId, (Authentication) accessor.getUser()))
                    return message;
                else
                    throw new BadCredentialsException(
                            String.format("you do not have privilege to this organization: %s", orgId));
            }
            return message;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception: ", e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterSendCompletion(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel, boolean sent, @Nullable Exception ex) {
        final StompHeaderAccessor accessor = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);
        final String destination = accessor.getDestination();
        if (StompCommand.SUBSCRIBE == accessor.getCommand()
                && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(destination)
                && destination.contains("conversations?orgId=")) {
            String orgId = destination.substring(destination.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);
            if (WebSocketAuthenticatorService.hasPermissionToOrgId(orgId, (Authentication) accessor.getUser()))
                webSocketUtils.publishConversationsForOrgId(orgId);
        }
    }
}
```

How we are sending messages to clients:

```
 this.simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend(
                ApplicationConstants.ORG_WEBSOCKET_TOPIC_PATH + orgId, conversationBO);
```